# How to get string subpath in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have some data loaded from db and appended to html like below:

```
<td>
  <p class="namepath" ng-bind-html="getNamePath(l)"></p>
</td>
```

My controller:

```
$scope.getNamePath = function (l) {
    let namepath = l.currpath;
    let t = namepath.split('/').map(function (text, i) {
        return '<span ng-click="changeNamePath(' + i + ',' + namepath + ')"' + i + '>' + text + '</span>';
    }).join('/');
    return t;
};
```

My l.currpath has some data like this:

`l.currpath = a/b/c/d`...

When you click on c I want to return `a/b/c`, click on b I want to return `a/b`...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but the idea is to use Array.indexOf and Array.slice and Array.join methods:

```
    let t = namepath.split('/');
    let i = t.indexOf(pathNameFromButtonClick);
    let finalNamePath = t.slice(0, i+1).join('/');
    return finalNamePath;
```

Comment: how can get i from: let i = t.indexOf(pathNameFromButtonClick);?

Comment: based on your description, its button name on which you click (you mentioned click on b ... )so, I am expecting you have code to get this b and pass this to indexOf

Comment: how can get this action? I don't know how can get action from onclick b in angularjs?, now I only get action from all text l.currpath.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-bind-html` directive does not compile AngularJS directives such as `ng-click`. Instead use something like:

```
<td>
  <p class="namepath">
     <span ng-repeat="namePath in l.currpath.split('/')"
           ng-click="changeNamePath($index, l.currpath)"
     >
       {{namePath}}<span ng-hide="$last">/</span>
     </span>
  </p>
</td>
```

Comment: I know, but 'a/b/c'  I load from db, how can append ng-click to body?